# Does jQuery selector iterates through all elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have multiple links on my page and I want to create the same event handler for all of them.

In the first example I am just using a selector and it creates the event handler correctly for both of the links:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.link').on('click', function () {
        alert($(this).text() + ' was clicked');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#' class='link'>Link1</a>
<a href='#' class='link'>Link2</a>
```

In the second example, I iterate through each element and create the event handler for every single one of them:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.link').each(function(){
      $(this).on('click', function(){
        alert($(this).text() + ' was clicked');
      });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#' class='link'>Link1</a>
<a href='#' class='link'>Link2</a>
```

Both are producing the same result, but why? Does jQuery selector already iterates through all the elements? Does jQuery selector **always** iterates all elements or only in certain scenarios?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery .each() - Practical uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722815/jquery-each-practical-uses)

Comment: @LW001: The question that you have linked explain how each works, which is great... what I don't understand is: Does jQuery selector automatically iterate through all selectors? It seems it does... does jQuery selector always iterate through selector or are there particular scenarios?

Comment: @HoomanBahreini I think this answers your question: [How can I learn how jQuery selectors work behind the scenes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631711/how-can-i-learn-how-jquery-selectors-work-behind-the-scenes)

Comment: @GeorgeSun: that's really a different question, it's asking how does jQuery selector find an element.

Comment: If I'm understanding it correctly you're looking for [Implicit iteration](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/jquery-basics#:~:text=getters%2C%20setters%2C%20and%20implicit%20iteration), TL;DR: Selecting (`$('.link')`) returns a selection, like a list of items. Depending on what you do with it, implicit iteration might take place (Usually with setters like `.on()` in your example), if you need a function that doesn't implicitly iterate (Usually Getters) you'll want to iterate yourself using `.each()`

Comment: @LW001: Thanks, that link that you have put there is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept you're looking for is called [Implicit iteration](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/jquery-basics#:%7E:text=getters%2C%20setters%2C%20and%20implicit%20iteration).

It is mentioned in the [jQuery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/each/) for `.each()`:

> Note: most jQuery methods that return a jQuery object also loop through the set of elements in the jQuery collection — a process known as implicit iteration. When this occurs, it is often unnecessary to explicitly iterate with the `.each()` method.

Selecting something using `$('.link')` returns a selection, which is like a list of items meeting the criteria laid out in your selector (Elements with the class `link` in this case). The selection itself does not iterate over anything, it just provides you with a list of items.

Depending on what you do with the Selection afterwards, implicit iteration might take place. That is for example the case with most setters (in your case [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler)). Setters will iterate over the selection and apply to all items in it.

Functions that don't implicitly iterate (Usually Getters) are where you want to iterate yourself using `.each()` if you need them run on multiple items.